# How to return the input time as always 09:00:00 in Python

Tags: python

```
    def dailyChecksInputDates():
        current_date = datetime.now()
        weekday = current_date.strftime("%A")
        if weekday.upper() == 'MONDAY':
            return datetime.now() - timedelta(days=3)
        else:
            return datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)

print(ParametersUtil.dailyChecksInputDates())
```

Here date is returning right. But I need the time should be returning always 09:00:00. Any chances of returning as required?

Comment: I should need the return time be always 09:00:00 whereas it is returning current date time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) of `datetime` module.

```
current_date = datetime.now().replace(hour=9, minute=0, second=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

While creating current date use the combine function of datetime:

```
datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.time(9, 0, 0))
```

`datetime.date.today()` - this will give you the current date

`datetime.time(9, 0, 0)` - this will give you 09:00:00

Comment: Nice one, I like another approach, but I think `replace` is a bit easier ;)